# Why won't this animation selector get called?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, selector

OK, I know there are tons of questions like this, but for some reason I can't figure out why the hell this callback selector doesn't get called?

Here are two methods which I added to a new view-based template.
I linked up a button to the IBAction, and a UIView to the redRect outlet.

The animation works fine, but for some reason which I can't figure out, the callback isn't called.

```
- (IBAction)toggleView:(id)sender {
    float target;
    if (redRect.alpha == 0.0) target = 1.0;
    else target = 0.0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finished)];
    redRect.alpha = target;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)finished {
    NSLog(@"Why won't this get called?");
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here - This is so simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to call `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:]`.  Otherwise, how would it know who to call?

Comment: We've all been there.  It'd be nice of Apple to do a warning NSLog for setting targets without a delegate, but oh well (downside of that is it's a performance hit).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];`